# Corona SDK variable throughout different scenes

Tags: coronasdk

I would like to know how to manage variables in corona throughout different scenes.
In my game score variable is in every scene what i want to know is how to continuously add the score per scene, because every time the scene changes the score automatically becomes zero.

Comment: Don't use global variables as many suggested.
user2653067 provided good answer. You can also create object that will manage passing variables for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate file. Example:

```
mydata.lua
```

With a table:

```
local M = {}
return M
```

--
Then in your game.lua you can simply require it:

```
local mydata = require( "mydata" )
```

and use for example a score:

```
mydata.score = 0
```

In your highscore.lua or whatever you can call it easy pzy:

```
local mydata = require( "mydata" )
```

and now you can use `mydata.score` saved value

Answer (score 1):

I hope Scenes are no more used . You can try the composer which is very effective and efficient .

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/index.html

It has two functions setVariable() and getVariable(). Using these functions you can pass your score from one scene to other .

since using of global variable may lead to memory leak, its better not use the global variabes

Answer (score 1):

## Solution Using Listeners and Custom Events

If all the scenes that need to know the score are loaded before the score is initialized or changed, this can accomplished with listener functions.  If the changes to any given scene that result from a change of score are minor (for example, only the value displayed in a TextObject changes), this approach keeps the view of each scene up to date and allows you to switch between scenes without pausing to update the display.

In each `scene:create()`, objects that need to respond to a change in score are given a listener function which is called when the Runtime receives a custom event (named "scoreChange" in this example) and which makes the necessary changes:

```
function scene:create( event )

    ...

    local score = display.newText( "0", 0, 0, native.systemFont )

    function score:scoreChange( event )
        self.text = tostring( event.score )
        return false --To allow the event to propogate to other EventListeners
    end
    Runtime:addEventListener( "scoreChange", score )

    self.score = score    -- lets us retrieve this object easily

    ...

end
```

Whenever the score is changed, the custom event "scoreChange" is dispatched with the new score value.  For example:

```
local function adjustScore( deltaScore )

    local score = tonumber( scene.score.text )  -- TextObject with score easily retrieved
    score = score + deltaScore

    local event = {
        name = "scoreChange",
        score = score
    }
    Runtime:dispatchEvent( event )

end
```

The Runtime catches this event and calls the method `scoreChange()` on all the table listeners it has registered for it.

For this approach to work, the scenes with these listeners must all be loaded before the score can be affected by user input/actions (the `scene:create()` function needs to be called to set up the listeners), eg.

```
composer.loadScene( "scene1" )
composer.loadScene( "scene2" )
...
composer.gotoScene( "scene1" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the global variable in any of your classes(`main.lua` is preferable) as:

```
  _G.myGlobalScoreVal = 100;
```

Then you can access it from any of your scene

```
 print("My Score is:".._G.myGlobalScoreVal) -- print the pre-setted value (here 100)
```

Keep Coding......................... :)

Answer (score 0):

Better Easy to create a Global Variable in Main.Lua, then you can use that variable all over the project. Initialize the global variable when u declare it without using 'local'.

Answer (score 0):

Either use "_G." before each variable and use on all screens.

For example:
In a class1.lua declare the object as:

```
_G.object1 = 8000
```

and use this in another class class2.lua as:

```
print("class1 global variable name : " .. _G.object1)
```

it will print its value.
_G. make a variable global.

or you can declare variable in main.lua and use it throughout all screens.

For example:
If we hide status bar in main.lua as:

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
```

the status bar will be hidden in all the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable in `main.lua` file with use "_G." before  variable

Answer (score 0):

Just to AVOID confusion:

The use of `_G.` is just for keeping track of what is global and not local, if you drop the `_G.`, it will still be placed inside the global table.

The real difference is if you use local before the variable/table or not.